# Kendo UI Grid for MVC export to Excel does nothing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, excel, export-to-excel, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using Kendo grid for MVC 4.0. I have the latest DLL `2015.1.318.440`. I am including `jszip.js`. I copied and pasted the code from the example:

```
          .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())
          .Excel(excel => excel.FileName("Enrollments.xlsx"))
```

It does nothing. The button changes color and that's it. I don't get any errors when I try it. It just doesn't do anything. I am not using a proxy server. I am running this in Chrome latest version.

The grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Trawick.Agents.Models.EnrollmentPolicy>()
.Name("grid")
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Excel())              
    .Excel(excel => excel
   .FileName("Enrollments.xlsx")
       .Filterable(true)
       .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Enrollments"))
     )              
     .Columns(columns =>
      {
       columns.Bound(p => p.enrollment_date)
          })
     .Pageable()
     .Groupable()
     .Sortable()
     .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
     .Ajax()
     .PageSize(20)
     .Read(read => read.Action("Enrollments_Read", "Enrollments")))
)
```

The controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Excel_Export_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
    {
        var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
    }
    public ActionResult Enrollments_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int? id)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM EnrollmentPolicy ";
        sql += SearchParams.SetSearch(this);
        return Json(GetEnrollments(sql).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

Bundle file including jszip

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/kendo")
     .Include("~/Scripts/jszip.js")
     .Include("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")
     .Include("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));
```

Comment: It's very hard to answer this question. post more code or give more info.

Comment: Post the entire code you used

Comment: Where are you putting those lines of code?

Comment: The `_Save` method isn't needed in most browsers, it exists only for those browsers that don't allow saving from javascript. Debug your javascript code (eg by using the F12 tools of your browser) to find any javascript errors that prevent your code from working. Also try using Fiddler or the Network Capture functionality of your browser to see whether the Ajax call for the data succeeds or not

Comment: I've tried it both ways. F12 doesn't reveal any js errors; HOWEVER, when clicking the button, Fiddler shows NO activity at all from that action. Hmmm...

Comment: I tried it with ForceProxy set to true and it still doesn't call the controller method. I'm betting the problem is not with the export function, but with the toolbar button.

Comment: Can you try with including jszip from any of the CDN. http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.4.0/jszip.js or http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1029/js/jszip.min.js

Comment: I tried both, in the bundle and at the top of the page where the grid is. Still the button does nothing. This is a trial version of Kendo, but I understand that to be fully functional...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/kendo")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendo.all.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jszip.js"));
```

This was the issue.jszip has to be included AFTER the kendo scripts (this is the opposite of what the documentation says).

Comment: This saved me a lot of time, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was related to volume - smaller number of records work, large batches do not. My current workaround is to set AllPages(false) and then it will just export a filtered list. See http://www.telerik.com/forums/excel-export-not-working-with-more-than-a-thousand-records

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you need to do like this I think.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Excel_Export_Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
    {
        var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

        return File(fileContents, contentType, fileName);
    }
```

cshtml

```
 .Excel(excel => excel
    .FileName("Enrollments.xlsx")
    .Filterable(true) //omit this if you don't need filtering in excel
    .ProxyURL(Url.Action("Excel_Export_Save", "Grid")) // for browsers not supporting saving file from JS
 )
```

Refer the demo code [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/excel-export) and for documentation, go through this [link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridExcelBuilder)

Comment: This isn't needed. This is the *fallback* code in case saving from Javascript fails. It's even mentioned in the comments of the cshtml code. This will only help if the browser can't actually save from Javascript. All modern browsers support this though

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now - Export button doing nothing. I was running the Q3 2014 version of Kendo.

Upgrading to the latest DLL and updating to the latest JavaScript libraries and styles fixed this for me.